# What can cause the center of the bed to be higher than the sides?

Tags: bed-leveling, glass-bed, bed

I find it impossible to level the printer recently. I read a couple of articles on bed warping but that refers to having the center of bed lower than the sides (collapsing on its own weight warm up after warm?) but what I experience is the opposite: the center is higher than the sides. Did anyone face this situation and how did you solved it? I use an Anycubic Chiron so the bed is pretty big.

Comment: Try to use borosilicate glass no the surface to help it. It can help you reduce the height differences between sides and center. You can also use a thin silicone pads to add flexiblity.

Other than that the bolts holding to heat place must be little misplaced so enlarging the top plates holes can reduce stress on plate so it wont bend.

Comment: Are you asking what can cause this (subject) or how to adjust for this (body)?

Answer (score 1):

As the Anycubic Chiron has an automated bed leveling, you can just calibrate that differences in height in the printer's firmware. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RudXmCgobso) is the official tutorial made by Anycubic :)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: Honestly, Chiron auto bed leveling is a marketing prop. Do it manually will get far better result..